# amcharts5 with weird tick behavior for very small numbers in logarithmic plot

Tags: amcharts, amcharts5

When plotting numbers in the range of 1e-10 to 1e-7, as shown in the upper graph, then the tick labels smaller than 5e-9 do not show up nor the ticks smaller than 1e-9. When multiplying the numbers by 1e+10, so shifting up the whole graph, everything's fine, as can be seen in the lower panel.

Is there any workaround to force amcharts to show also the ticks for smaller values or at least the ticks and labels at the major logarithmic levels like 1e-10?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aUYtL.jpg)

---

I played around with minorGridEnabled, and minGridDistance, which sometimes works but not for all ranges of numbers. Ecspecially it fails when zooming in to get only numbers within a range of 1e-10 to 1e-9. Then there are plenty of ticks and labels, far too much. extraMin also does not work.

```
var yAxis = chart.yAxes.push(am5xy.ValueAxis.new(root, {
  logarithmic: true,
  //extraMin: 0.5,
  min: min_p_Metall,
  renderer: am5xy.AxisRendererY.new(root, {
    minorGridEnabled:true,
    //minGridDistance: 20,
    pan:"zoom"
  })  
}));
```